# M2: Is there a faster way to Update Frontend Themes?

Tags: magento2, frontend

When updating frontend components in Magento 2, meaning Templates as phtml, html templates for Knockout, CSS files, Less Files, Fonts, Images etc.

I can only get this to work by

1. Flushing the `/var and /pub/static` folders
2. running `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` for each language
3. Clearing all Caches in Magento
4. Clearing all Caches in Browser

Needles to say, this whole process is pretty annoying and slow. The Magento 2 Docs show parameters to skip Themes in the deploy command, but they don't work. The whole generation takes really long and stops me from being productive. Is there no faster way to update the Frontend designs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**From Magento version 2.1 you can deploy only specific theme,**
Just run below command to update only specific theme,

YOu can pass just require information to below command, only run specific theme

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --area=frontend --no-fonts --theme Magento/luma
```

Extra theme are not deployed.

Comment: Just returns the error Message 
[RuntimeException]
  The "--area" option does not exist.

Is it possible, that this is only available in the newest M2 versions?


Generally it still doesn't seem a practical solution to me, as each theme takes several minutes to process. If I just change 1-2 lines of css and want to see if it works or if some other css setting overrides my changes, then I need a fast way to check this. If I wait a few minutes for every change I cannot work in a productive manner.

Comment: which version are you used?

Comment: currently developing in 2.06. Will need to update soon, but as it is currently being tested I don't want to touch it. Also anything above 2.1x requires PHP5.6, while my development VM runs 5.59

Comment: so you cant do theme specific deployment, you have to upgrade version

Comment: You can do it faster using directly changes inside pub/static folder and after complete changes you have to add your updated code inside core or module files. Using this you doesnt need to run command every time.

Comment: Yes that is actually what I'm doing right now. It's not a nice solution, but better than generating all content every time.

Comment: yes, if you want nice solutions then upgrade your version, otherwise do lenghty process. Thanks.

Comment: You can close this questions after accept as solutions.

Comment: Sure, I'm just hoping someone has a fully automated solution for this. I can't imagine that all Magento Devs use the deploy methods